# HYPERLINK with variable (column name or cell) containing the carrier's Tracking Number

Tags: excel, hyperlink

My spreadsheet now contains FedEx, UPS and a regional carrier. For approximately, five shipments and three or so purchases per day, I hyperlink these tracking numbers myself each day.

Is there a way to us either my column called "TRACKING" OR the cell in the column for each row to create the unique hyperlink for each row?

I can create two extra columns to do this because I don't know how to use the IF function to make a decision between if it is UPS (1Z...) versus FedEx (always numbers).

The manual hyperlinks I am using are:
http://wwwapps.ups.com/ietracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum=
https://www.fedex.com/insight/findit/nrp.jsp?tracknumbers=

And of course I have a column with the tracking number shown (happens to be column I). All info regarding each transaction is fully contained in the row. Only one transaction per row.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you're asking.

Say your column I has the UPS/FedEx numbers.  Put this formula in B1 and drag down:
`=IF(LEFT($I1,2)="1Z",HYPERLINK("http://wwwapps.ups.com/ietracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum="&$I1,"UPS Link"),HYPERLINK("https://www.fedex.com/insight/findit/nrp.jsp?tracknumbers="&$I1,"FedEx Link"))`

The way the If statement works is this:  It looks in your cell I1 (again, assuming your tracking numbers are there), and looks at the left most two characters.  If they're "1Z", then it uses the `hyperlink()` function to create the link to UPS, otherwise it uses the FedEx URL.